# Localizing jquery validation with asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, jquery-globalization

I am using Asp.Net Mvc3 and the unobtrusive jquery validation. I'd like to have my dates validation localized, I mean, jquery is validating my date as being MM/dd/yyyy but I would like it to be dd/MM/yyyy.

I'm trying to use the jQuery Globalize plugin (http://github.com/jquery/globalize).
I added references to the scripts globalize.js and globalize.culture.pt-BR.js and when my page loads I'm running the follwing script:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
    Globalize.culture("pt-BR");
  });
}).call(this);
```

The jQuery UI plugin works as charm, but the validation doesn't.
What else am I missing?

**Edit:**

Using the links in the answer below I solved the problem using the [Globalize plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize):

Of course, I had to add a reference to the Globalize plugin in the page and also a reference to the culture that I wanted to use (all available on the plugin's site). After that is just a small piece of JavaScript code.

```
Globalize.culture("pt-BR");
$.validator.methods.date = function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value);
};
```

Comment: If you have the time, please update your question with the solution you give at brodie's answer. It would be really useful to have it here instead of hidden in the comments :) thanks!

Comment: Just did what you asked. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are doing any work with internationalization and ASP.NET MVC I highly recommend reading through these two excellent posts by Nadeem Afana

- [ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization - Part 2 (NerdDinner Demo)](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx)

In his second post he has a detailed example of using the jQuery UI datepicker and discusses the issues with localization.

In his example he mentions the following

```
@* Unfortunately, the datepicker only supports Neutral cultures, so we need to adjust date and time format to the specific culture *@
    $("#EventDate").change(function(){
      $(this).val(Globalize.format($(this).datetimepicker('getDate'), Globalize.culture().calendar.patterns.d + " " + Globalize.culture().calendar.patterns.t)); /*d t*/
    });
```

i also recommend downloading the Nerd Dinner internationalization demo linked on his site.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is not with the datepicker is with the validation plugin. Even if I don't use the datepicker, the validation plugin says that I have an invalidate.

Comment: But thanks anyway, that article you mentioned had some valuable info for solving the problem. I did de following: $.validator.methods.date = function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value);
}

Comment: For clarity I made a small post explaining how a I solved it. http://bit.ly/ouK8hl

Answer (score 17):

I've been doing similar myself recently.  I started by following the advice in Scott Hanselman's blog on this topic - you can read about this here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

I had to make some changes to use Globalize instead of jQuery Global (now jQuery Global is dead). I wrote this up in the following blog post in case that's helpful:

http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html

My blog post features a link to this script jquery.validate.globalize.js which forces jQuery Validate to use Globalize for number / date / range parsing.  The date part of this is the part that should probably solve your issue:

https://raw.github.com/gist/3651751/68cbccd0fdd4725a8d6fd1b5568bb33d27fb1eff/jquery.validate.globalize.js

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.7.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="globalize.js" />

/*!
* Monkey patch for jquery.validate.js to make use of Globalize.js number and date parsing
*/

$(document).ready(function () {

    var currentCulture = $("meta[name='accept-language']").prop("content");

    // Set Globalize to the current culture driven by the meta tag (if any)
    if (currentCulture) {
        Globalize.culture(currentCulture);
    }

    //Tell the validator that we want numbers parsed using Globalize.js
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {    
        if (Globalize.parseFloat(value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Tell the validator that we want dates parsed using Globalize.js
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        if (Globalize.parseDate(value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Fix the range to use globalized methods
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
        range: function (value, element, param) {
            //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value
            var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
            return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Little correction of Johnny Reilly answer:

```
 $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {    
    if (Globalize.parseFloat(value)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

must be replaced with

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
}
```

for correct parsing of zero string ("0").

So entire code is:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.7.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="globalize.js" />

/*!
* Monkey patch for jquery.validate.js to make use of Globalize.js number and date parsing
*/

$(document).ready(function () {

    var currentCulture = $("meta[name='accept-language']").prop("content");

    // Set Globalize to the current culture driven by the meta tag (if any)
    if (currentCulture) {
        Globalize.culture(currentCulture);
    }

    //Tell the validator that we want numbers parsed using Globalize.js
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {    
       return !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    }

    //Tell the validator that we want dates parsed using Globalize.js
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        if (Globalize.parseDate(value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Fix the range to use globalized methods
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
        range: function (value, element, param) {
            //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value
            var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
            return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
        }
    });

});
```