# MVC3 MvcContrib Grid filter date validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

I've set up a MvcContrib Grid with paging and filtering as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/08/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-using-the-mvccontrib-grid-and-pager.aspx). It all works great, except when I try to add filtering by date.

My web configuration includes:

```
<globalization
   uiCulture="en-GB"
   culture="en-GB"
/>
```

I'm using the jquery datepicker to enter the date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js", function () {
                $("input[type='datetime']").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The dates show as dd/mm/yy during data entry in the filter. 
They show as dd/mm/yy in the controller.
But in validation they are treated as mm/dd/yy.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came back to this problem and got it working, thanks to the link to Scott Hanselman's Blog.

First I downloaded the jquery.global plugin from Nuget.Then I added the following lines to my _layout.cshtml

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.globalize/globalize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.en-GB.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this to the system.web section of web.config:

```
<globalization
   uiCulture="en-GB"
   culture="en-GB"
/>
```

This has got it working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem mate: [JQuery Datepicker Will not post with UK date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138539/jquery-datepicker-will-not-post-with-uk-date-string)

Personally I gave up and validated with javascript, and disabled the unobtrusive jquery, which I think where the conflict was coming from.

Although a poster on my question thread pointed this way, which could be useful:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Comment: I've looked at that. Everywhere I can see the thread culture is en-GB.