# MVC3 Validation with ComponentModel.DataAnnotations for UK date format (also using jquery ui datepicker)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation, data-annotations

I see there are some similar questions to this, but none solve my issue.

I am working on an MVC3 app with Entity Framework 4.3. I have a  UK date field that i plan to allow the user to edit using the Jquery UI datepicker (which i got working thanks to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)).

Fortunately for me this blog includes instructions on making the datepicker using UK format, however, the EF validation is still telling me that i need to enter a valid date format. Wierdly it doesn't prevent me from submitting the date to the DB its just the unobtrusive validation kicking in and displaying the message.

At the moment I have the following data annotation:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime Module_Date { get; set; }
```

but i have also tried adding:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

which had no effect at all. I hope some one has a solution because i don't fancy turning off the unobtrusive validation to stop this error message.

Thanks

**EDIT**

following @Iridio answer, i looked into adding a Model Binding, and indeed from the few posts like this one that i read it seemed to be the right thing to do, but what i have come up with has no effect. here is what i have tried:

```
public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var date = value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        return date;
    }
}
```

with this in the `Application_Start()` method of the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeBinder());
```

Comment: I believe your referring to the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations rather than the EntityFramework data annotations?  If you followed the blog through then do you specify the data format `{dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"}` in your client side script?  If so, what version of the jquery ui script are you using?

Comment: oooh you are quite correct i am using the ComponentModel ones. I got used to using the EF ones on last project. will update. I was using jquery ui 1.8.7 but i have updated to the latest as per your answer below to no avail

Comment: oh and yes i have specified `{dateFormat:"dd/mm/yyyy"}`

Comment: To clarify, it is the client side validation (not the server side validation) that is complaining that the date is not in the correct format?  _validation is still telling me that i need to enter a valid date format_.  The reason I am going down this route is that I had this problem this week from the exact same blog.

Comment: yeah thats right, i should have been more clear. it is the client side validation. The default value is set to todays date (13/4/2012 which is invalid for US) on the create page, and if you don't change it and just click save it will happily add it to the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, the problem was with the jquery validate scripts insisting on using the US datefomat. I will restrain my self from going on a proper rant about the fact that the majority of the world uses dd/mm/yyyy though.

Anyway, eventually i found the answer to my woes in a comment to an answer of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438754/localizing-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-3), the author of which kindly wrote a [blog post](http://vintem.com.br/en/2011/09/17/globalizacao-de-validacao-do-jquery-com-o-asp-net-mvc-3/) about how he solved the issue.

Basically I have used the [jquery globalize script](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) and just set the culture to `en-GB`. I should mention that in his blog he doesn't mention where to put the bit where you specify the culture, so i just shoved in in script tags in the page under the references to the globalization scripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize.culture.en-GB.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Globalize.culture("en-GB");
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: It really shouldn't be necessary to go to all this trouble just to make UK date validate!!  But thanks for the info I was stuck on this one.  Just hope jQuery add a more elegant way of doing this soon.  That script globalize.js (ironically spelt with a z :) ) file is pretty big.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I agree, I shouldn't have to do that, and infact its not a very good solution for alot of cases because it always forces UK format dates.

Comment: I've been searching for two days for a resolution to this problem, with the finger eventually pointing to JQuery for the reasons you mention. This fix has worked perfectly for me - although the easiest way to implement it was to use nuget to add the jquery-globalise package - and if you do that, then the script locations become /Scripts/globalize/globalize.js and /Scripts/globalize/culture/globalize.culture.en-GB.js

Answer (score 1):

You have to write you own ModelBinder for the DateTime type.

This is a binder that I wrote for a similar problme but with Decimal type (maybe you will need it). you should grasp the idea and adapt it to your need

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
  public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
    ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
    object actualValue = null;
    try
    {
      actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
      modelState.Errors.Add(e);
    }

    bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
    return actualValue;
  }
}
```

Then in global.asax you register your binder and you're done

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  //Here you tell how to hendle the specific type 
  ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
}
```

**UPDATE**

After your clarification [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224046/394028) should help

Comment: tried a similar approach to this, but cant make it work, i have updated my question with my attempt

Comment: Updated the answer to use globalize in your client side validation

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a bug in the script version of the jquery ui datepicker that ships with the  mvc3 framework (jquery-ui-1.8.11.js).

If you specify the date in the uk format (as indeed the blog states):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
});
```

then jquery-ui-1.8.11.js seems to have an issue with validating the date and keeps asking for a valid uk date (but the validation appears random).  If you change the date format to "mm/dd/yy" then this issue will go away but thats no good for uk dates.

The issue has been resolved in a later version of that library so download the latest version (I believe 1.8.18 at time of writing) or reference the cdn:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: it looks like i am using a slightly older version (1.8.7) so swapped in the new one, and it made no difference. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have found a better solution here.... by #fretje

[Override jquery date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866172/override-jquery-date)

I have modified his/her code slightly though so that it can still take date formats like 30 May 2012 below.

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "date",
        function (value, element) {

            //Added to validate dates like 31 May 2012
            if (value.split('/').length === 1) 
                return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));

            var bits = value.match(/([0-9]+)/gi), str;
            if (!bits)
                return this.optional(element) || false;
            str = bits[1] + '/' + bits[0] + '/' + bits[2];
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(str));
        },
        "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
    );

    $global.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem just now, took me hours to track down the reason. I'm not saying this is your issue but after having spent hours switching globalisations on everything, etc. i thought I'd post the issue on here for any people struggling like me.

Anyway, the problem in my project was actually not what i thought it was. I had decorated the property with `[DataAnnotationsExtentions.Date]` which, it turns out, mucks up the client side validation in chrome when it comes to the localisation (i.e if you want a day after the 12th in England) although it seems to work fine in other browsers. As soon as I removed that it worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by some reason if you put a class called "date" in your textbox, Chrome just get crazy as discribed here at [this blog](http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2012/01/tricky-times-using-mvc3-date-validator.html). I had the same problem and I just changed the class name to customDate and it was solved.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers